# problem with it showing the extra column in table

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table*}
\hfill{}

\begin{tabularx}{150mm}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Input Parameters}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\pi$ = 0.2} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\pi$ = 0.5} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\pi$ = 0.8} \\
\cline {4-15} 

 \multicolumn{3}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Existing} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{MAHA } & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Existing } & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{MAHA} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Existing } & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MAHA}\\

\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {Migration Status} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Migration Size} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Interaction Size} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} \\ 
 \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please provide the solution.

Comment: Please add the code producing your current table to allow us to check for problems with it. Maybe it is just as simple as that you defined a column too much for your table.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem, would be helpful. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \begin{table*}
\hfill{}
  
\begin{tabularx}{150mm}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Input Parameters}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\pi$ = 0.2} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\pi$ = 0.5} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{$\pi$ = 0.8} \\
\cline {4-15} 

 \multicolumn{3}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Existing} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{MAHA } & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Existing } & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{MAHA} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Existing } & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MAHA}\\

Comment: I added the code over here

Comment: Provide the solution to what?

Answer (score 2):

probably you looking for the following:

[image]

with `tabularx` environment you need to use at least one `X` column:

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{150mm}{|*{15}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Input Parameters}} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$\pi$ = 0.2}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$\pi$ = 0.5} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$\pi$ = 0.8} \\
\cline {4-15}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Existing} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MAHA } 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Existing } 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MAHA} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Existing } 
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MAHA}\\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {\ Migration Status\ } 
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Migration Size}  & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Interaction Size}  
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT}            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} 
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT}            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} 
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT}            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} 
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT}            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} 
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT}            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} 
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{SimT}            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Delta$SimT} \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Thank you . Another question how to increase size of the cell as the text in second row first cell is quite squeezed. It need to be centered. what should i do for it

Comment: add some empty  space to text ... see edited answer

Comment: How to add empty space for example for the value "Migration status"

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim, see edited answer.

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim, any news? is answer now acceptable for you?